# Implementing a table in a PySNMP agent

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I'm implementing a table using PySNMP as an SNMP agent.

I've followed the (PySNMP source) architecture of using an auto-generated TRS-MIB.py file, and a manually written __TRS-MIB.py file which contains the implementation.

I have made a working (2 row) table, but the code is really ugly, so there must be a better way of doing it.  (Also, both rows will always have the same values, which is a bug.)

__TRS-MIB.py:

```
# Imported just in case new ASN.1 types would be created
from pyasn1.type import constraint, namedval
import time

# Imports

( Integer,
  ObjectIdentifier,
  OctetString, ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
  "ASN1",
  "Integer",
  "ObjectIdentifier",
  "OctetString"
  )
( Bits,
  Integer32,
  ModuleIdentity,
  MibIdentifier,
  MibScalar,
  MibScalarInstance,
  TimeTicks, ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
  "SNMPv2-SMI",
  "Bits",
  "Integer32",
  "ModuleIdentity",
  "MibIdentifier",
  "MibScalar",
  "MibScalarInstance",
  "TimeTicks"
  )

class TrsDeliveryTime(Integer32):
  def clone(self, **kwargs):
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['value'] = int(time.time())
    return Integer32.clone(self, **kwargs)

class TrsMessagesPerHour(Integer32):
  def clone(self, **kwargs):
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['value'] = -int(time.time())
    return Integer32.clone(self, **kwargs)

class TrsGatewayIndex(Integer32):
  def clone(self, **kwargs):
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['value'] = 0
    return Integer32.clone(self, **kwargs)

class TrsGatewayName(OctetString):
  def clone(self, **kwargs):
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['value'] = 'SMG0'
    return OctetString.clone(self, **kwargs)

class TrsGatewayState(OctetString):
  def clone(self, **kwargs):
    if 'value' not in kwargs:
      kwargs['value'] = 'UP' + str(int(time.time()))
    return OctetString.clone(self, **kwargs)

# Objects
( trsDeliveryTime,
  trsMessagesPerHour,
  trsGatewayTable,
  trsGatewayEntry,
  trsGatewayIndex,
  trsGatewayName,
  trsGatewayState, ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
  'TRS-MIB',
  'trsDeliveryTime',
  'trsMessagesPerHour',
  'trsGatewayTable',
  'trsGatewayEntry',
  'trsGatewayIndex',
  'trsGatewayName',
  'trsGatewayState', 
  )
__trsDeliveryTime = MibScalarInstance(trsDeliveryTime.name, (0,), TrsDeliveryTime(0))
__trsMessagesPerHour = MibScalarInstance(trsMessagesPerHour.name, (0,), TrsMessagesPerHour(0))
__trsGatewayIndex0 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayIndex.name, (0,), TrsGatewayIndex(0))
__trsGatewayName0 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayName.name, (0,), TrsGatewayName(0))
__trsGatewayState0 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayState.name, (0,), TrsGatewayState(0))
__trsGatewayIndex1 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayIndex.name, (1,), TrsGatewayIndex(0))
__trsGatewayName1 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayName.name, (1,), TrsGatewayName(0))
__trsGatewayState1 = MibScalarInstance(trsGatewayState.name, (1,), TrsGatewayState(0))


# Augmentions

# Exports

# Objects
mibBuilder.exportSymbols("__TRS-MIB",
                         trsDeliveryTime=__trsDeliveryTime,
                         trsMessagesPerHour=__trsMessagesPerHour,
                         trsGatewayTable=trsGatewayTable,
                         trsGatewayIndex0=__trsGatewayIndex0,
                         trsGatewayName0=__trsGatewayName0,
                         trsGatewayState0=__trsGatewayState0,
                         trsGatewayIndex1=__trsGatewayIndex1,
                         trsGatewayName1=__trsGatewayName1,
                         trsGatewayState1=__trsGatewayState1,
                         )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretending this is a beautiful code, here's some optimization to your initial version. It's not tested as I do not have your TRS-MIB file at hand.

The idea is to specialize MibScalarInstance class (to make it serving different columns) by overriding its readGet() method which returns a var-bind pair to be reported back to SNMP Manager.

You should be able to run this MIB with the stock [CommandResponder](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/current/v3arch/agent/cmdrsp.html), just make sure to load up your MIB on startup.

```
import time

# Import managed objects
( trsDeliveryTime,
  trsMessagesPerHour,
  trsGatewayIndex,
  trsGatewayName,
  trsGatewayState, ) = mibBuilder.importSymbols(
  'TRS-MIB',
  'trsDeliveryTime',
  'trsMessagesPerHour',
  'trsGatewayIndex',
  'trsGatewayName',
  'trsGatewayState', 
  )

# Columnar managed objects instances implementation

class TrsDeliveryTimeInstance(MibScalarInstance):
  def readGet(self, name, val, *args):
    if name[-1] == 0:  # Row #0
      return self.name, self.syntax(int(time.time()))
    elif name[-1] == 1: # Row #1
      return self.name, self.syntax(time.time()//2)
    else:
      MibScalarInstance.readGet(self, name, val, *args)

class TrsMessagesPerHourInstance(MibScalarInstance):
  def readGet(self, name, val, *args):
    if name[-1] == 0: # Row #0
      return self.name, self.syntax(-int(time.time()))
    elif name[-1] == 1: # Row #1
      return self.name, self.syntax(-time.time()//2)
    else:
      MibScalarInstance.readGet(self, name, val, *args)

class TrsGatewayIndexInstance(MibScalarInstance):
  def readGet(self, name, val, *args):
    if name[-1] == 0: # Row #0
      return self.name, self.syntax(0)
    elif name[-1] == 1: # Row #1
      return self.name, self.syntax(1)
    else:
      MibScalarInstance.readGet(self, name, val, *args)

class TrsGatewayNameInstance(MibScalarInstance):
  def readGet(self, name, val, *args):
    if name[-1] == 0: # Row #0
      return self.name, self.syntax('SMG0')
    elif name[-1] == 1: # Row #1
      return self.name, self.syntax('SMG1')
    else:
      MibScalarInstance.readGet(self, name, val, *args)

class TrsGatewayStateInstance(MibScalarInstance):
  def readGet(self, name, val, *args):
    if name[-1] == 0: # Row #0
      return self.name, self.syntax('UP' + str(time.time()))
    elif name[-1] == 1: # Row #1
      return self.name, self.syntax('DOWN' + str(time.time()))
    else:
      MibScalarInstance.readGet(self, name, val, *args)

# Instantiate and export managed objects instances
mibBuilder.exportSymbols(
  "__TRS-MIB",
  # Row #0
  TrsDeliveryTimeInstance(trsDeliveryTime.getName(), 0, trsDeliveryTime.getSyntax()),
  TrsMessagesPerHourInstance(trsMessagesPerHour.getName(), 0, trsMessagesPerHour.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayIndexInstance(trsGatewayIndex.getName(), 0, trsGatewayIndex.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayNameInstance(trsGatewayName.getName(), 0, trsGatewayName.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayStateInstance(trsGatewayState.getName(), 0, trsGatewayState.getSyntax()),
  # Row #1
  TrsDeliveryTimeInstance(trsDeliveryTime.getName(), 1, trsDeliveryTime.getSyntax()),
  TrsMessagesPerHourInstance(trsMessagesPerHour.getName(), 1, trsMessagesPerHour.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayIndexInstance(trsGatewayIndex.getName(), 1, trsGatewayIndex.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayNameInstance(trsGatewayName.getName(), 1, trsGatewayName.getSyntax()),
  TrsGatewayStateInstance(trsGatewayState.getName(), 1, trsGatewayState.getSyntax())
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.  When I use this, I get an error `AttributeError: Integer32 instance has no __call__ method` at the time that I query an index column value.  If I query one of the Octet Strings column values, I get `AttributeError: OctetString instance has no __call__ method`.  It looks like there's one more level of function invocation than expected, or similar.

Comment: P.S. I had to change the `...getName(), 0, trs...` for `...getName(), (0,), trs...` to make it run.

Comment: P.P.S. Changing the `0` for `(0,)` only made it run, the code still produces the attribute error when queried.

Comment: P.P.P.S. It looks like the calls to self.syntax(...) are at fault.

Comment: P.P.P.P.S Replacing all calls to `self.syntax(...)` with `self.syntax.clone(...)` fixes the issue and I now have working tables.  Many thanks for your help on this.